# I am learning spring using tutorials and I am stuck. I am not able to solve the problem and getting 404 error in browser

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have been facing this issue with past few days but still not able to solve this issue. I have read all the previous answers in stack overflow. I am getting 404 file not found in browser and *WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/chaljayrr/add] in DispatcherServlet with name 'firstOne' in console*.

**Web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>firstOne</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>firstOne</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**firstOne-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd ">



    <ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
    <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.chalja"></ctx:component-scan>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
   </beans>
```

**FirstController.java**

```
package com.chalja;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class FirstController {

     @RequestMapping("/add")
        public String add(){
            return "display.jsp";
        }
}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<form action="add">
    <input type="text" name="t1"><br />
    <input type="text" name="t2"><br />
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.chalja</groupId>
  <artifactId>chaljayrr</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>chaljayrr Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>




  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>chaljayrr</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

**disply.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
display page

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try with action="/add"

Comment: Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

The url mentioned in RequestMapping is /add..try using /add from browser / REST client. Also, in your controller method just return "display".

Since you have configured a bean of InternalResourceViewResolver, it will automatically figure out the path where the jsp is located -in your case /WEB-INF/display.jsp.